# Inspect the type of a Swift closure

Tags: xcode, cocoa, types, swift, introspection

How can I programatically inspect the type of a `Swift` object? Something similar to obtaining the class of an object in ObjectiveC with the `class` message.

So, if I have

```
func f(x: Int) -> Int{
    return x * 3
}
```

I want to get `(Int)->Int` as the type of f.

Comment: Yes, in Xcode. Where else? O:-)

Comment: I didn't get what you meant earlier. Will have a look later. :-)

Comment: Why? You structure your code so that you expect closures of a certain type, and the compiler will complain if it doesn't match. This _should_ obviate the need for type checking. If you show why you need to do this, perhaps we can show you a better way.

Comment: @AlexWayne: In fact, I don't think that it's even *possible* to write code not to expect closures of a certain type known at compile-time.

Comment: @cfisher: But you know the type of `f`. It's written in your code. In what situation can you imagine that you don't know it?